# string data type creating run time error for a particular test case in c++ program

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++17, runtime-error

For the codeforces problem:

https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/339/A

The following program shows a runtime error on the 7th test :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    cin>>s;
    int i;
    string a,b,c;
    int j=0,k=0,l=0;
    for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='1')
        {
            a[j]='1';
            a[j+1]='+';
            j+=2;
        }

        if(s[i]=='2')
        {
            b[k]='2';
            b[k+1]='+';
            k+=2;
        }

        if(s[i]=='3')
        {
            c[l]='3';
            c[l+1]='+';
            l+=2;
        }
    }
    char str[100];
    int x,y,z;
    for(x=0;x<=j-1;x++)
    {
        str[x]=a[x];
    }

    for(y=0;y<=k-1;y++,x++)
    {
        str[x]=b[y];
    }

    for(z=0;z<=l-1;z++,x++)
    {
        str[x]=c[z];
    }

    int q;
    for(q=0;q<=x-2;q++)
    {
        cout<<str[q];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the test case was:

> 2+3+3+1+2+2+2+1+1+2+1+3+2+2+3+3+2+2+3+3+3+1+1+1+3+3+3+2+1+3+2+3+2+1+1+3+3+3+1+2+2+1+2+2+1+2+1+3+1+1

The answer was accepted when I changed `string a,b,c;` to `char a[100],b[100],c[100];`

I am unable to understand why the `string` datatype here led to a runtime error.

I guessed it might be due to the length of the test case, but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 5):

Given

```
string a,b,c;
```

`a`, `b`, and `c` are all zero length strings. Therefore

```
    if(s[i]=='1')
    {
        a[j]='1';
        a[j+1]='+';
        j+=2;
    }
```

is an error because `j` is an out of bound access on the (zero length) string `a`.

This is the incredibly common misunderstanding that if you assign to strings (or vectors) they grow to accommodate whatever index you are assigning to.

The correct code is

```
    if(s[i]=='1')
    {
        a.push_back('1');
        a.push_back('+');
    }
```

`push_back` does grow the string by adding a character to the end.

Note that this version has the advantage that you don't have to track the size of the string in a separate variable. So you can eliminate the variable `j`, thus simplifying the code.

```
for(x=0;x<a.size();x++)
{
    str[x]=a[x];
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much. I had a doubt if u don't mind....if a, b and c are zero length strings then how come the program gave correct output for 2+3+1 , 1+2++3+3+2+2 ,etc.

Comment: @indomitable_fire_2010 Because it's perfectly possible for bugged programs to run as was expected. There is no rule in C++ that says a bugged program **must** fail, only that it **may** fail. For short strings your program did not fail, but for long strings it did. This is normal for C++.

Comment: thank you very much for resolving my doubt